# Android: Do NOT save sent messages when sending via SmsManager

Tags: android, smsmanager

Is it possible with `SmsManager` to not save sent message at all?

This is how I send my messages:

```
String phoneNumber = "9999999999";
String smsBody = "Message from the API";

// Get the default instance of SmsManager
SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
// Send a text based SMS
smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, smsBody, null, null);
```

To be more clear, I want to hide the sent message from the user, so that if the user opens the default SMS app the sent messages won't be displayed.

If this can be done then I'd really like to know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Android KitKat (4.4) this is not possible unless you are the "Default SMS App" or you integrate with an API provided by an app that is the default.

See the Blog post here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html

Prior to that it was the default behavior to *not* record messages.

The only SMS App I am aware of that allows API integration is "Super Duper Messaging Manager" (http://superdupersms.com/)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Well I guess that is necessary when it comes to security. But thanks for answering :)